# Haskell Array Pattern in a function

Tags: arrays, haskell, pattern-matching

Hi total Haskell beginner here: What does the pattern in a function for an array look like ? For example: I simply want to add +1 to the first element in my array

```
> a = array (1,10) ((1,1) : [(i,( i * 2)) | i <- [2..10]])
```

My first thought was:

```
> arraytest :: Array (Int,Int) Int -> Array (Int,Int) Int
> arraytest (array (mn,mx) (a,b):xs) = (array (mn,mx) (a,b+1):xs)
```

I hope you understand my problem :)

Comment: You can’t pattern match arrays. Look up the functions documented in Data.Array online.

Comment: The immutable arrays in the `array` package aren't really meant to be used like that. An immutable array is best created "all at once", either using one of the high-level creation functions or by freezing an `STArray` or `IOArray`. Once it's created, you normally don't want to modify it; doing so is quite expensive if the array is large. I don't know of any production-quality Haskell libraries for really high-performance immutable array-like structures, but there have been some promising experiments in recent years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pattern match on arrays because [the `data` declaration in the `Data.Array.IArray` module for the `Array` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array-IArray.html#t:Array) doesn't have any of its data constructors exposed. This is a common practice in Haskell because it allows the author to update the internal representation of their data type without making a breaking change for users of their module.

The only way to use an `Array`, therefore, is to use the functions provided by the module. To access the first value in an array, you can use a combination of `bounds` and `(!)`, or take the first key/value pair from `assocs`. Then you can use `(//)` to make an update to the array.

```
arraytest arr = arr // [(index, value + 1)]
  where
    index = fst (bounds arr)
    value = arr ! index
```

If you choose to use `assocs`, you can pattern match on its result:

```
arraytest arr = arr // [(index, value + 1)]
  where
    (index, value) = head (assocs arr) -- `head` will crash if the array is empty
```

Or you can make use of the `Functor` instances for lists and tuples:

```
arraytest arr = arr // take 1 (fmap (fmap (+1)) (assocs arr))
```

---

You will probably quickly notice, though, that the `array` package is lacking a lot of convenience functions. All of the solutions above are fairly verbose compared to how the operation would be implemented in other languages.

To fix this, we have the [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package (and its cousins), which add a ton of convenience functions to Haskell and make packages like `array` much more bearable. This package has a fairly steep learning curve, but it's used very commonly and is definitely worth learning.

```
import Control.Lens

arraytest arr = arr & ix (fst (bounds arr)) +~ 1
```

If you squint your eyes, you can almost see how it says `arr[0] += 1`, but we still haven't sacrificed any of the benefits of immutability.

Answer (score 1):

This is more like an extended comment to @4castle's answer. You cannot pattern match on an `Array` because its implementation is hidden; you must use its public API to work with them. However, you can use the public API to *define* such a pattern (with the appropriate language extensions):

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns #-}
-- PatternSynonyms: Define patterns without actually defining types
-- ViewPatterns: Construct patterns that apply functions as well as match subpatterns
import Control.Arrow((&&&)) -- solely to dodge an ugly lambda; inline if you wish

pattern Array :: Ix i => (i, i) -> [(i, e)] -> Array i e
-- the type signature hints that this is the array function but bidirectional
pattern Array bounds' assocs' <- ((bounds &&& assocs) -> (bounds', assocs'))
-- When matching against Array bounds' assocs', apply bounds &&& assocs to the
-- incoming array, and match the resulting tuple to (bounds', assocs')
  where Array = array
  -- Using Array in an expression is the same as just using array

arraytest (Array bs ((i,x):xs)) = Array bs ((i,x+1):xs)
```

I'm fairly sure that the conversions to and from `[]` make this absolutely abysmal for performance.